# How to dynamically shift a DIV down based on predecessor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint, css-position

I've got a series of DIVs, all with the same class (.ms-acal-item). What I'm trying to do is get the position of each one, compare it to the one above it, and shift it down if needed. This is to correct an issue on a SharePoint 2013 calendar where event tiles are overlapping. Here's my code so far:

```
$(function() {

   $('.ms-acal-item').each(function(i, obj) {
    var tile = jQuery(this);
    var prev = tile.prev();
    var prevPos = prev.position();
    var tilePOs = tile.position();
    var curTop = parseInt(tilePos.top);
    var newTop = parseInt(prevPos.top) + 30;
    if(curtop !== newTop){
    tile.css('top', newTop);
    }
   });

});
```

And here's an example of what the SharePoint-generated content looks like:
[image]

Each tile is 20px high and positioned absolutely in-line. What I need to do is compare the position of each tile to its predecessor and then move it down 30px if it isn't already there (20px for the tile and 10px between them). So far it's not working - my code seems to have no effect on the tile positions.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: We're gonna need some sort of example/demo to reproduce this and find an answer. I assume your ms-acal-item class has position relative or absolute as one of its css properties?

Comment: @RicardoRuiz - they have position:absolute as one of the inline properties, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the logic, while processing the first element we do not have any previous element, so we need to ignore it and few typo(variable case issues) mistakes in your code. Below is the revamp code.(**To see the changes effect i changed style from top to margin-left, correct it afterwards**)

```
$(function() {
   $('.ms-acal-item').each(function(i, obj) {
    var tile = $(this);
    var prev = tile.prev();
    if (typeof prev.position() !== "undefined") {
        var prevPos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prev.position()));
        var tilePos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tile.position()));
        var curTop = parseInt(tilePos.top);
        var newTop = parseInt(prevPos.top) + 30;
        if(curTop !== newTop){
        tile.css('margin-left', newTop);
        }
    }
   });

});
```

Comment: This appears to work for a second as the page loads, but then the tiles go back to their previous positions. I'm thinking now that something else in the page is overriding it. The way that SharePoint 2013 generates content is pretty wonky. Regardless, I'll accept your answer.